# Limpiar div &nbsp; con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HOLA!**

Necesito saber como puedo borrar/limpiar el elemento `<div>&nbsp;</div>` de un articulo (texto).
Para especificar, tengo dentro de `<div class="contenido capitalizar">` lo siguiente

```
<div>texto</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>texto</div>
```

Necesito que   se limpie con una funcion en jquery para que pueda tomar el siguiente parrafo en el recorrido que hace un for. Como se podria limpiar ese   para que pueda tomar los div p que necesito?
Nota: el texto debe comenzar desde el segundo parrafo.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
function getRemove(){
    var elemtHtml = document.querySelector(".contenido,.capitalizar");
    var parrafos = elemtHtml.querySelectorAll("div,p,li");
    var nodeH =parrafos.getElementById(".contenido,.capitalizar").children.length
     if (nodeH='&nbsp;'){
     for (var i=1;i<nodeH;i++){
         document.getElementById("div").children[1].remove()
     }}
} 

function getTexto() {
    var elemtHtml = document.querySelector(".contenido,.capitalizar");
   var parrafos = elemtHtml.querySelectorAll("div,p,li");
   var texto = "";
   
   for (let index = 1; index < parrafos.length; index++) {
       
       texto += parrafos[index].innerText;
       var m= getRemove();
   
   }
   
   return texto.trim();
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías seleccionar el *Non-breaking Space* a través de su valor **Unicode** en vez de a través de su **HTML Entity**.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div:contains("\u00a0")').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>texto</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>texto</div>
```

**JQuery** goza del selector `:contains` que nos permite seleccionar un elemento por su contenido textual. Aprovechándome de este y buscando el *Non-breaking Space* a través de su valor **Unicode**, puedes seleccionar los `<div>` que lo contenga para posteriormente borrarlos o hacer con ellos los que necesites.

Comment: Gracias!! Lo pruebo con unicode en ese caso :)